# Querying with WP query using meta key price

Tags: query, order

Could somebody tell me what's wrong with my WP query please? I'm trying to order my posts by price and price is an ACF (a textbox which has a number in it)

```
            $args = array (
                'post_type'     => 'product',
                'post__in'      => $post_ids,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'meta_key' => 'tour_price',
                'meta_query' => array(
                   array(
                   'key'       => 'tour_price',
                   'compare'   => '=',
                   'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                   )
                ),
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'meta_value_num'` - Order by numeric meta value (available with Version 2.8). Also note that a `'meta_key=keyname'` must also be present in the query. This value allows for numerical sorting as noted above in `'meta_value'`.

Try to use like this :

```
 $args = array (
            'post_type'     => 'product',
            'post__in'      => $post_ids,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_key' => 'tour_price',
            'meta_query' => array(
               array(
               'key'       => 'tour_price',
               'compare'   => '=',
               'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
               )
            ),
        );
```

Comment: Thansk, works <3

Comment: It's my Duty :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `meta_query` in your code. And also you don't need to check numeric value of meta field like that. To sort by numeric value, in your `orderby` parameter, you should use `meta_value_num` instead.

So this will be your `WP_Query`.

```
$args = array (
  'post_type'    => 'product',
  'post__in'      => $post_ids,
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key' => 'tour_price',
);
```